# SSD or CD in Lowest SATA address in a new computer build?

Tags: ssd, computer-building

I'm building my first computer. One website says to connect the CD to the lowest SATA interface, so that the BIOS will recognize it, and allow Windows to be loaded on the HDD, but I want to load Windows on an SSD. The SSD install information is all about an existing operational computer, not a new build, and that says replace the lowest numbered SATA HDD with the SSD, migrating the software first. Which device should go in the lowest SATA address the CD or SSD?

Comment: This isn't my area, but I'm not seeing any conflict in the instructions.  The first instruction says CD lowest, which would make any HDD higher.  Second instruction says to replace the lowest HHD, which would still leave the CD as lowest.  Whether it is a new build or existing, that wouldn't seem to affect the instructions.  What am I missing?

Comment: The instructions you've read are useless. IDE used to use primary and secondary master and slave which provided the "1st, 2nd, 3rd & 4th" priority order of devices. SATA eliminates this as your BIOS allows you to choose whichever priority boot device you please by changing the boot order in the "Boot" menu. Install your SSD and DVD drive in whichever SATA sockets you please (some boards have 3Gb/6Gb sockets - SSD in the 6Gb) -> go to BIOS and set CD as first boot device (initially) to install Windows. When Windows is installed go back to BIOS and set the SSD as first boot device.

Comment: some older systems did rely on sata bus order for certian boot time operations, but it really isn't necessary. if all else fails, most bioss use F12 to access a boot menu where you can specify the device you want to boot from, so just make sure your hdd/ssd is the default boot device, and use the boot time menu if you need to boot off other media on rare occasion.

Comment: Get the manual, for your exact motherboard, from the motherboard manufacturer website, what it says is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a BIOS where this would really matter.  Install them however you like.  The BIOS should let you pick which one to boot from (though by default it will be the lowest-numbered one).  You only need to boot from the CD(DVD) once, but most of the time the boot process will not boot from CD(DVD) unless you press a key anyway, and the BIOS will skip completely blank hard drives as well, so it should work the way you need it to either way.